# Android equivalent of getActivity() from/in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-actionbaractivity

Like my title says, i'm looking for an equivalent of `getActivity()` in my `ActionBarActivity` class in my `Android project`.

I want to pass an `Activity` parameter in `AsyncTask` declaration object, because i'm using an `Activity` object in my custom `AsyncTask` extended class

Here an example simplest code of my project

```
public class EventCreator extends ActionBarActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_even_creator);
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_even_creator,null);
    this.context = this.getBaseContext();

    final Button createButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createEventButton);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> eventCreatorSend = new SendEvents(/* here need activity object */);
            eventCreatorSend.execute();
        }
    });

}

    class SendEvents extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

        public Activity act;

        SendEvents(Activity a) {
            this.act = a;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ((LinearLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.layout_loader_create_event)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean params) {
            if (params){

                ((LinearLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.layout_loader_create_event)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                act.finish();
            }
            else {
                ((LinearLayout)act.findViewById(R.id.layout_loader_create_event)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(act,"Fail to send event",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    };
}
```

In a time, i thought use `getParent()` from `ActionBarActivity` class, but it return a null object.
So how to get the Activity object i want in `ActionBarActivity` class ?

Comment: Ok, where exactly are you trying to use this in your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try nameofactivity.this instead `getActivity()`

I always use `getActivity()` in `Fragments` Activities and .this in any other kind of `Activity`.

Answer (score 4):

Oh damn !
I just found a solution just after posting my ask.

I use *MyClass.this*, and it's done. Like this :

```
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> eventCreatorSend = new SendEvents(EventCreator.this);
    eventCreatorSend.execute();
```

Hope that's can help someone !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is an Activity variable

```
// in your fragment
Activity myActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    //fragment shouts "i know my father!!!"
    myActivity = activity; //
}
```

now your activity instance(The father) can be represented anywhere