# What is the best way to get Context throughout an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I save to SharedPreferences within a single Activity several times. Each time I do reads or writes, I pass the `Context`. Following are the two options I am thinking about - which one is better (or is there a better way)

1. Everytime I need to pass context to a function in another class (for ex a class writing to my SharedPreferences), I am passing the this `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.
2. Should I just save a variable once in the `onCreate()` of the Activity (i.e. `Context ctxt = getActivity().getApplicationContext()`) and then use the variable `ctxt` throughout the Activity whenever I need to pass context.

Which way is technically better? Key is - should I be accessing `getApplicationContext()` each time. I am guessing that is slow (& unnecessary) and also probably causes crashes (I've been seeing some logs from my users that I am unable to reproduce but the stack traces always point to lines containing `getApplicationContext()`)

Comment: It's quite unlikely _getApplicationContext()_ gives you crash but _getActivity()_ may return null. I'm assuming you are saving preferences from Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity itself can be used as the Context. Simply pass `this`. You can pass `ActivityName.this` inside an inner class.

`getApplicationContext()` returns "the context of the single, global Application object of the current process."

Answer (score 0):

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496286/android-equivalent-of-getactivity-from-in-actionbaractivity/30496423#30496423) its what you want, and you just use the `Activity` as `Context` and there is no problem calling `getApplicationContext()` anytime you want, you just might need to find alternatives to that and maybe use `getBaseContext()` or the activity itself

Comment: dont forget to upvote any post that helps you :) just saying Sir